# El uso de "que" para hacer una pregunta otra vez o precisar una pregunta

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

En varias películas observé el idiomático uso siguiente de "*que*" en diálogos.

De "Hogar" (España):

Hombre: *-¿Qué quieres?*

Mujer: *-¿Tienes algo que esconder?*

Hombre: *-¿**Que** qué quieres?*

De "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

Madre: *-¿Quién te llamó ayer al instituto?*

Hijo: *-¿Qué?*

Madre: *-**Que** quién te llamó ayer al instituto.*

De "Contratiempo" (España):

*-¿Le conoces?*

*-¿Eh?*

*-**Que** si le conoces.*

Otro ejemplo de "Contratiempo": -*¿Niños?*

-*¿Eh?*

*-**Que** si tienes hijos.*

Otro ejemplo de "Contratiempo" (durante una llamada):

*-voy a necesitar una grúa por favor. Sí.*

*-...*

*-¿**Que** dónde estoy?*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo usar esta estructura? ¿En cuáles circunstancias?
2. ¿Sería gramaticalmente incorrecto no usar "*que*" en estos ejemplos?
3. ¿Cómo cambiaría el significado si no usara "*que*" en estos ejemplos (si esto es posible y correcto gramaticalmente)?

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores  si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En este caso, "que" se usa para repetir algo que el hablante o su interlocutor no entendió bien, o dice no haber entendido bien. La conjunción "que" permite omitir el sujeto que dice o pregunta algo:

> Madre: -¿Quién te llamó ayer al instituto?
>
> Hijo: -¿Qué?
>
> Madre: -Que (= Te estoy preguntando) quién te llamó ayer al instituto.

> -¿Le conoces?
>
> -¿Eh?
>
> -Que (= Te pregunto) si le conoces.

> -¿Niños?
>
> -¿Eh?
>
> -Que (= Te pregunto) si tienes hijos.

> -¿Dónde está?
>
> -¿Que (= Me pregunta) dónde estoy?

Comment: entiendo. Solo querría aclarar más la segunda pregunta. ¿Se puede repetir solo la misma pregunta sin usar "que"? ¿O nativos siempre usa "que" en estos casos y nunca sin "que"?

Comment: Se puede omitir "que". Se usa solo para vincular con lo ya dicho, pero no es imprescindible.